# request mysql with curl

Tags: mysql, curl

I have a mysql running. I can access it with

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -P 8009 -p
```

(password requested)

Now I want to make requests with curl :

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8009 ????
```

I need to pass the password and some simple commands (INSERT in one database)

Is it possible/ how to do that ?

**EDIT** :
Since it seems impossible, I broaden the scope of the question.

I'm open to wget or whatever to makes simple commands in a mysql base without installing specific utilities (mysql itself, python packages, etc.). So using commonly available commands in bash.

I have no real control on the environment from which I will make the requests.

Comment: This smells like an XY-problem: 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

In short: There's no nice/neat way to speak MySQLs protocol with easy tools, it's a binary protocol optimized for efficiency.
If really neccessary, install a webserver on the MySQL server (or another host) which will take HTTP(S)-requests (from curl, wget, etc.) and send them to the database.

Comment: @Tobias Mädel My X-problem is : I want to create a Milvus-mysql docker compose. But the milvus container has to wait that mysql is not only up but to have created a database "milvus". And the milvus docker has not "mysql" in it.

Comment: @Tobias Mädel Anyway, the Y problem is interesting by itself because, for testing/debug purposes, it can be handy to make "curl ..." without installing mysql on the client side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You can't.

`curl` is a HTTP client. MySQL doesn't use the HTTP protocol.

There was apparently a [plugin that added a HTTP API](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-5-7-labs-inserting-updating-and-deleting-records-via-http/), but the MySQL Labs page says this:

> These binaries were created by MySQL testing servers.
>
> They are **NOT FIT FOR PRODUCTION**.
>
> They are provided solely for testing purposes, to try the latest bug
> fixes and generally to keep up with the development.
>
> - Please, DO NOT USE THESE BINARIES IN PRODUCTION.

So you're out of luck.

Comment: Thank for the answer. In fact I'm not totally stuck to curl. I edited the question to be less specific.

Comment: @LaurentClaessens MySQL uses a proprietary protocol. You will need MySQL-specific, or at least database-specific, tools.

Answer (score 3):

Using password is only possible in the browser-based
[REST API for MySQL Cloud Service](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/mysql-cloud/CSMCS/use-curl.html).

It does not apply to your case - the protocol to communicate with MySQL is not HTTP,
so you cannot use an HTTP client like cURL.

Comment: Thank for the answer. In fact I'm not totally stuck to curl. I edited the question to be less specific.

Comment: You can't get away from using a MySQL client of some kind.